# Unable to Fetch values out of NSDictionary in Asynchronous Request

Tags: asynchronous, swift

Actually i am trying to get a response using Async Request. Therefore I am trying to fetch data from the dictionary, but i unable to do so. I want to do the following in SWIFT
   NSString *s = [jsonObject valueForKey:@"EmployeeID"];

Please help me, thanks.

```
   NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue()) { (urlResponse, data, error) -> Void in
        if let err = error {
            completion("")
            return
        }
        var err:AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?>
        let jsonObject:AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)as NSDictionary

        var jsonResult = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        NSLog("Data : \(jsonResult)")
```

Comment: What's the question? Why are you unable to fetch? Compilation error, no data, exception, whatever?

Comment: Actually i am trying to get a response, which is in form of json. json is being displayed correctly... But, i need to get values of a particular Key.

Comment: Then you should detail that in your question. As it is now it's unclear what you are asking and what the problem is.